# How to refactor this to prevent multiple API calls in angular foreach loop

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, nosql

Right now I am asking an API for a count of people in each city in an array. The page is loading slowly though because for each city I send a request to my API to get the count of people in it.

How can I prevent myself from making multiple API calls in a loop like this?

Lets say I have 7 cities in my controller:

```
$scope.cities = ['Phoenix', 'Dallas', 'Washington', 'Sacramento', 'San Diego', 'Chicago', 'Seattle'];
```

I'm looping through them in my view to create a list item for each one:

```
<li ng-repeat="city in cities">{{city}}</li>
```

Now I want to display the count of all people in each city. My mongoose model structure looks like this:

```
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', {
    city: String,
    fname: String,
    lname: String
});
```

Right now in my controller I'm doing something like this to get a count of each city, and pass it to the view:

```
angular.forEach($scope.cities, function(city) {
    Person.query({city: city}, function(data) {
        $scope.count[city] = data.length;
    });
});
```

I don't feel as if this is efficient though since it makes 7 requests to the API on page load, and if I add more cities it will bog down the page.

Should I keep an active set of count documents in a separate collection? Just looking to see what a better option would be.

Comment: You can send multiple cities in your request, but the API needs to support it.

Comment: You should change your API the way  @Icycool said and create the request on page loading so you will have a small initial delay but not more then that.

Comment: you should change your api logic, make it something that you will send an array of cities and on basis of that array return what you want to return